# Filter only one or more elements while using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would to print only some and not all elements of an array that will be printed using ng-repeat.

The array is stored in `$scope.userRecipes = []`.

In the HTML I use:

```
<li ng-repeat="f in  userRecipes" class="list-group-item">

...

<div class="row panel-body" ng-show="!f.isCollapsed">
<hr>
<div class="col-md-6">
   <h3>{{f.trigger.triggerType | capitalize}} trigger</h3>
      <div ng-repeat="(key, data) in f.trigger" ng-if="!(key == 'triggerType')
         || !(key == 'lastCheck')
         || !(key == 'sender')
         || !(key == 'gaid')
         || !(key == 'ctid')
         ">
      <h4>{{key | reformat | capitalize}}:</h4> {{data}}
      </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
   <h3>{{f.action.actionType | capitalize}} action</h3>
      <div ng-repeat="(key, data) in f.action" ng-if="key.toString().localeCompare('actionType') || data.notNull() || !data">
      <h4>{{key | reformat | capitalize}}:</h4> {{data}}
   </div>
</div>
</div>
...

</li>
```

But this solution (`ng-if="!(key == 'triggerType') || !(key == 'lastCheck') || ..."`) is not working for me. It works only if I set a single condition: `ng-if="!(key == 'triggerType')"` works if leaved alone. If I use `ng-if="!(key == 'triggerType') || !(key == 'lastCheck')` it does not work.

Note that `reformat` and `capitalize` are two AngularJS `myApp.filters(...)`.

Summary: the goal is to make sure that the `ng-repeat` **ignores** those elements that have some specifics key or data (without printing empty HTML lines).

Comment: `!(key == 'triggerType') || !(key == 'lastCheck') || !(key == 'sender') || !(key == 'gaid') || !(key == 'ctid')` is always true. You need logical AND instead of OR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, data) in filteredTriggers(f.trigger)">
    <h4>{{key | reformat | capitalize}}:</h4> {{data}}
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.filteredTriggers = function(triggers) {
    var result = {};
    angular.forEach(triggers, function(value, key) {
        if (['triggerType', 'lastCheck', 'sender', 'gaid', 'ctid'].indexOf(key) == -1) {
            result[key] = value;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The logic in your `ng-if` is flawed. You're returning true if any of the conditions are true, so you're getting true on every iteration. You want the logical `and` operator, not `or`.

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, data) in f.trigger" ng-if="!(key == 'triggerType')
         && !(key == 'lastCheck')
         && !(key == 'sender')
         && !(key == 'gaid')
         && !(key == 'ctid')
         ">
```

Now you're returning true if all of them are true, which is what you really want.